# Phonegap 2.8.0 (iOS) online/offline events not firing

Tags: ios, cordova

Has anybody else had any similar experience?
I have this app working fine on Android, but in iOS the online/offline events are not firing.

As far as I know I have everything set up correctly, and I can even use the 'FileTransfer' plugin, but my online/offline event handlers are not being called.

With the following test app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <script charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            function onDeviceReady() {
                console.log("Device is ready!");
                document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
                document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
            }

            function onOnline() {
                console.log("Device is online!");
            }

            function onOffline() {
                console.log("Device is offline");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get 'Device is ready!' reported to the console, but beyond that I get nothing.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work by putting the event listeners above the on device ready.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <script charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
            document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

            // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
            //
            function onDeviceReady() {
                console.log("Device Ready");
            }

            // Handle the online event
            //
            function onOnline() {
                console.log("Online");
            }

            function onOffline() {
                console.log("Offline");
            }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Strange, though, b/c the docs apparently recommend otherwise: 'Typically, you will want to attach an event listener with `document.addEventListener` once you receive the Cordova `'deviceready'` event.' ([here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#online))

Comment: In PhoneGap < 3.0, you needed to attach the listeners after `device ready`. It changed with PhoneGap 3.0. See the relevant docs.

Comment: @JustinD. I'm using 2.8.0 in this project...?

Comment: As of cordova/phonegap 3+ This is enabled when you install the network plugin `phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information`. After you've done this, you can use [HTML5 online/offline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Online_and_offline_events)